# Как удалить из файла строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Это Python 3.7.7

```
def show_catalog ():
    with open (file_name) as file:
        lines = file.readlines ()
        file.close()
    for line in lines:
        print (line())
def write_in_catalog (product):
    with open (file_name,'a') as file:
        file.write (product)
def buy_a_product (product):
    with open (file_name,'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        lines.remove (product)
```

Все равно из файла не удаляется.

Comment: любую строку? или строку которая содержит что-то определённое?

Comment: ну элемент типа 'str'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947833/deleting-a-line-from-a-file-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064184/remove-lines-from-textfile-with-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/using-python-for-deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно считать весь текст файла поместить в переменную
Потом, удалить из текста нужную строку

Удалить строку по номеру

```
with open("file") as f:
    res = f.readlines()

#номер строки что нужно удалить
n = 0
res.pop(n)
print(res)
```